# Selecting files directly from photo library using HTML input type=file

Tags: html-input

I have an HTML page containing `<input id="imageOnly" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple />` If I load this page on a mobile browser (say Safari on iOS) and tap the button, it first shows a popup with a few possible actions and requires the user to pick one:

[image]

But is there a way to just directly go to photo library instead of being presented this popup?

If I use `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture/>` then it directly goes to camera without showing the popup and I'm wondering if there's a similar way to just directly go to photo library?

Comment: Do you find any solution for this?

Comment: Do you find any solution? @ArsalanMahmoodpour